Visual Studio project references that use Environment Variables in their path are not updated when the relevant Env Variable is updated
I have a .csproj which has a reference that utilizes a System Environment Variable in the Hint Path:
<Reference Include="MyLib">
  <HintPath>$(LIB_PATH)\bin\MyLib.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>

In the Env Variable LIB_PATH is set to "C:\mylibs\ver1.0".
I load the csproj and it resolves the reference path correctly. I then close Visual Studio.
Now I change the Environment Variable LIB_PATH to "C:\mylibs\ver2.0".
I load the csproj again and this time the reference path still points to "C:\mylibs\ver1.0". Only after deleting the visual studio solution options file (.suo) and loading the project again does the reference path get updated to "C:\mylibs\ver2.0". But in doing so, I lose all my prior working information such as breakpoints.
Is there a way to force Visual Studio to resolve the path? It does not seem to do it automatically.

What happen if you not delete .suo and just reload the project ?
